# Logstash: replace field values matching pattern

Tags: linux, logstash, kibana-4

I'm using Elasticsearch + Logstash + kibana for windows eventlog analysis. And i get the following log:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.04.16",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "Ov498b0cTqK8W4_IPzZKbg",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "EventTime": "2015-04-16 14:12:45",
    "EventType": "AUDIT_FAILURE",
    "EventID": "4656",
    "Message": "A handle to an object was     requested.\r\n\r\nSubject:\r\n\tSecurity ID:\t\tS-1-5-21-2832557239-2908104349-351431359-3166\r\n\tAccount Name:\t\ts.tekotin\r\n\tAccount Domain:\t\tIAS\r\n\tLogon ID:\t\t0x88991C8\r\n\r\nObject:\r\n\tObject Server:\t\tSecurity\r\n\tObject Type:\t\tFile\r\n\tObject Name:\t\tC:\\Folders\\Общая (HotSMS)\\Test_folder\\3\r\n\tHandle ID:\t\t0x0\r\n\tResource Attributes:\t-\r\n\r\nProcess Information:\r\n\tProcess ID:\t\t0x4\r\n\tProcess Name:\t\t\r\n\r\nAccess Request Information:\r\n\tTransaction ID:\t\t{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\r\n\tAccesses:\t\tReadData (or ListDirectory)\r\n\t\t\t\tReadAttributes\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\tAccess Reasons:\t\tReadData (or ListDirectory):\tDenied by\tD:(D;OICI;CCDCLCSWRPWPLOCRSDRC;;;S-1-5-21-2832557239-2908104349-351431359-3166)\r\n\t\t\t\tReadAttributes:\tGranted by ACE on parent folder\tD:(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;S-1-5-21-2832557239-2908104349-351431359-3166)\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\tAccess Mask:\t\t0x81\r\n\tPrivileges Used for Access Check:\t-\r\n\tRestricted SID Count:\t0",
"ObjectServer": "Security",
"ObjectName": "C:\\Folders\\Общая (HotSMS)\\Test_folder\\3",
"HandleId": "0x0",
"PrivilegeList": "-",
"RestrictedSidCount": "0",
"ResourceAttributes": "-",
"@timestamp": "2015-04-16T11:12:45.802Z"
  },
  "sort": [
    1429182765802,
    1429182765802
  ]
}
```

I get many log messages with different EventID, and when I recieve a log entry with EventID 4656 - i want to replace the value "4656" with a string "Access Failure". Is there a chance to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when you are loading with logstash -- just do something like this:

```
filter {
  if [EventID] == "4656" {
    mutate {
      replace => [ "EventID", "Access Failure" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of values, look at translate{}:

```
translate {
  dictionary => [
    "4656",  "Access Failure",
    "1234",  "Another Value"
  ]
  field => "EventID"
  destination => "EventName"
}
```

I don't think translate{} will let you replace the original field.  You could remove it, though, in favor of the new field.

Answer (score 0):

use replace filter:

---

Replace a field with a new value. The new value can include %{foo} strings to help you build a new value from other parts of the event.

Example:

```
filter {
 if [source] == "your code like 4656" {
   mutate {
    replace => { "message" => "%{source_host}: My new message" }
   }
 }
}
```